# How to match substrings in a set order with Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, search, matching

Given the word 'butterfly', I would like to return matches which only include 5 or more consecutive characters from 'butterfly'.

Test cases:

1. 'butter' would be a match.
2. 'terfly' would be a match.
3. 'bXutterfly' would be a match (matching the substring 'utterfly')
4. 'butt' would NOT be a match (less than 5 consecutive characters).

Current code is matching when it shouldn't because the 5 characters being matched are not consecutive, I understand this is because the string is inside the `[square braces]`:

```
const str = 'ylfrettbu';
const regex = new RegExp('[butterfly]{5,}', 'gi');
const matched = str.match(regex);
```

The string being matched must be dynamic hence: `new RegExp`

Comment: `/.*(butte|utter|tterf|terfl|erfly).*/`

Comment: You actually probably don't want to use regexes for this, but fuzzy matching.  Maybe someone more familiar with js will pop in, but in the meantime you might want to google `levenshtein`.  However, even this may not work for you.  Is `btter` acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `btter` would not be accepted as the letters are not all consecutive. I will have a look into fuzzy matching and levenshtein now. I think your answer below might solve my problem, I will test later and mark it as solving the questions if I can get it to work.

Comment: @PeterRhodes - I think Levenshtein is not going to work for you without editing source code if `btter` is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following regex on the string you want to match:

```
(?=(.{5}))
```

replace with (for each match)

```
$1|
```

https://regex101.com/r/dDJYh1/1

The result is the regex you can use on the actual data you're searching.  (`butte|utter|tterf|terfl|erfly` for `butterfly`)

I just noticed regex101 is not showing the breakdown below that it's showing on the right for the capture groups.  The capture groups on the *right* are correct.  I'm not quite sure how js breaks this down, so hopefully someone else can give you a more complete answer or edit mine.

I *really* don't know js, but this seems to do the trick:

```
var re = /(.)(?=(.{4}))/g;
var s = "butterfly";

var m = re.exec(s);
do {
    print(m[1]+m[2]);
    m = re.exec(s);
}while(m)
```

Comment: This is a great answer. As you mentioned the regex is slightly off as with Javascript the string gets split like this: `butte|butter|utterf|tterfl|terfly|erfly` with 6 character instead of 5 (apart from the strings at each end).

Comment: @PeterRhodes - The js above pulls out the correct matches (I split the regex up to consume 1 char which helps with different matching methods).  Honestly you could probably a build a loop which generates the regex WITHOUT using a regex just as easy, though :)

Answer (score 1):

ylfrettub would match the whole string. You can use something like b?u?t?t?e?r?f?l?y? which keeps the order of the words. Maybe you need a solution like the edit distance, levenshtein distance or something equal.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

I have found this by googling.
https://github.com/schulzch/edit-distance-js

It returns the difference between the words.

The edit distance of butterfly and butterXfly is 1.
The edit distance of butterfly and butterly is 1.
The edit distance of butterfly and butt is 5.
The edit distance of butterfly and bXuXtXtXeXrfly is 5.
The edit distance of butterfly and ylfrettub should be 8. I did not test it.